# How to select rows in html table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want the data inside the rows of [this table](http://www.hockey.de/VVI-web/default.asp?lokal=DHB&menue=/VVI-web/menue-HSR.asp&innen=/VVI-web/Ergebnisdienst/Spielplan-Schiedsrichter.asp). What must the command be in css-query? I used the [website of Jsoup](https://try.jsoup.org/), to find out the query, but in vain.

I want to parse the datas from the website and shows it in a Listview.

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT: Here is the html-Table
The

```html
<!-- Liste -------------------------------------------------->
<tr><td colspan="3"><table width="806" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 <tbody><tr>
 <td><p class="Zwischen">Tag</p></td>
 <td><p class="Zwischen">Uhr</p></td>
 <td><p class="Zwischen">Spiel</p></td>
 <td><p class="Zwischen">Liga</p></td>
 <td><p class="Zwischen">Schiedsrichter</p></td>
 <td><p class="Zwischen">Schiedsrichter</p></td>
 <td><p class="Zwischen">Beobachter</p></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><img src="/VVI-web/Include/dummy.gif" width="113" height="1"></td>
 <td><img src="/VVI-web/Include/dummy.gif" width="60" height="1"></td>
 <td><img src="/VVI-web/Include/dummy.gif" width="120" height="1"></td>
 <td><img src="/VVI-web/Include/dummy.gif" width="130" height="1"></td>
 <td><img src="/VVI-web/Include/dummy.gif" width="125" height="1"></td>
 <td><img src="/VVI-web/Include/dummy.gif" width="125" height="1"></td>
 <td><img src="/VVI-web/Include/dummy.gif" width="125" height="1"></td>
 </tr>
  
 <tr><td colspan="5"><img src="/VVI-web/Include/dummy.gif" width="1" height="4"></td></tr>
  
 <tr>
 <td class="bghell"><b class="rot">Sa. 21.09.2019</b></td>
 <td class="bghell">14:00</td>
 <td class="bghell">BWK - ETUF</td>
 <td class="bghell"><a href="/VVI-web/Ergebnisdienst/Ergebnisdienst.asp?lokal=DHB&amp;saison=FELD19&amp;liga=BND-BL2-D"><b>» BND-BL2-D</b></a></td>
  
 <td class="bghell"><a class="ohne" href="?lokal=DHB&amp;saison=FELD19&amp;modus=1&amp;persid=117256">M.Hildebrandt</a></td>
  
 <td class="bghell"><a class="ohne" href="?lokal=DHB&amp;saison=FELD19&amp;modus=1&amp;persid=176752">J.Ottmüller</a></td>
  
 <td class="bghell"><span class="rot"></span></td>
  
 </tr>
  
 <tr><td colspan="5"><img src="/VVI-web/Include/dummy.gif" width="1" height="4"></td></tr>
  
 <tr>
 <td class="bghell"><b class="rot">So. 22.09.2019</b></td>
 <td class="bghell">11:00</td>
 <td class="bghell">BHC - Klipper</td>
 <td class="bghell"><a href="/VVI-web/Ergebnisdienst/Ergebnisdienst.asp?lokal=DHB&amp;saison=FELD19&amp;liga=BND-BL2-D"><b>» BND-BL2-D</b></a></td>
  
 <td class="bghell"><a class="ohne" href="?lokal=DHB&amp;saison=FELD19&amp;modus=1&amp;persid=117256">M.Hildebrandt</a></td>
  
 <td class="bghell"><a class="ohne" href="?lokal=DHB&amp;saison=FELD19&amp;modus=1&amp;persid=176752">J.Ottmüller</a></td>
  
 <td class="bghell"><span class="rot"></span></td>
  
 </tr>
  
</tbody></table></td></tr>
```

Comment: Please paste your sample table and code here

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the API is available for this on this site. You need to have access to API for doing that. I can provide you the code to access all data in a table.

https://jsfiddle.net/u9pws36y/

```
<style>
  table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }

  td,
  th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }
</style>

<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

<table id="fetchDataTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>Computer</td>
      <td>3434</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn-medium btn-danger remove" id="mprDetailRemove">
          <i class="icon-remove"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>Stationary</td>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn-medium btn-danger remove" id="Button1">
          <i class="icon-remove"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>Stationary</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn-medium btn-danger remove" id="Button2">
          <i class="icon-remove"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  $(function(){
      $('#fetchDataTable').find('tr').each(function (data){
          var data = $(this).find('td');

          var arr = [];
          arr.push(data[0].textContent);
          arr.push(data[1].textContent);
          arr.push(data[2].textContent);
          alert(arr);
      });
    });
</script>
```